# Can't get default document to work with ColdFusion & IIS

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I've tried everything I can think of and it's definitely configured, but I cant get IIS to work with ColdFusion 10 and default documents.

I'm looking for some help or advice as to what to try, I've added the entries, verified they are in web.config etc., restarted IIS, restarted the web server, and it just won't work.

Comment: Can you browse to a cfml file without relying on the default document?

Comment: Does it work when you browse to www.yourdomain.com/index.cfm? What about www.yourdomain.com/index.html? (assuming both of those files exist).

Comment: yes both work directly, but as a default they dont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you place the `web.config` file? did you place it in the top level directory of your specific application/site?

I do and that works well.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.cfm" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.